# Logging in to a website with Jsoup which redirects, and scraping a page that isn't the redirect

Tags: java, redirect, authentication, web-scraping, jsoup

[This](http://interpals.net) is the website I'm trying to scrape from.

I'm able to login to the website fairly easily. However, I'm unable to retrieve and reuse the cookies or session ID to scrape a page other than the one the login page redirects to. I receive a 403 everytime.

Here is an example of what I've tried:

```
try
{
    String userAgent = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0";

    Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("http://www.interpals.net/login.php")
            .data("action", "login")
            .data("login", username)
            .data("password", password)
            .data("auto_login", "1")
            .userAgent(userAgent)
            .method(Connection.Method.POST)
            .followRedirects(false)
            .execute();

    res.parse();
    String sessionID = res.cookie("interpals_sessid");

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.interpals.net/friends.php").cookie("interpals_sessid", sessionID).get();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
try {    
    String url = "http://www.interpals.net/login.php";
    String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36";

    Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(userAgent)
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .execute();

    response = Jsoup.connect(url)
            .cookies(response.cookies())
            .data("action", "login")
            .data("login", "login")
            .data("password", "password")
            .data("auto_login", "1")
            .userAgent(userAgent)
            .method(Connection.Method.POST)
            .followRedirects(true)
            .execute();            

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.interpals.net/friends.php")
            .cookies(response.cookies())
            .userAgent(userAgent)
            .get();

    System.out.println(doc);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you! I've been fiddling all day and wasn't able to do it.

Comment: Thanks! I was stuck for a long time on this.